# Low cost 12V brushed DC motor driving - circuit review

Tags: microcontroller, dc-motor, attiny

I am looking to drive a 12 V DC motor (the application is a 3-speed fan) and I have a basic schematic drawing done and would like to request you all to review and provide feedback/improvements. My objective is to have an efficient and low-cost driving system.

Notes:

1. J2 will have to take both 12 V and 24 V DC input from battery.
2. J3 is a tactile or push button switch to control 3 speeds and OFF.
3. IC3 is a comparator to indicate if it is a 12 V or 24 V system.
4. ATTINY5 microcontroller and Q1 for PWM switching, I might add a Schottky diode parallel to the motor terminals J1.

[image]

Comment: Feeding IC3 with 24V while its VCC is only 5V will put it way out of spec (Vin max = Vcc-2).

Comment: The ATtiny 5 has an internal ADC, so you don't need the comparator, just measure VIN through a voltage divider.

Comment: Voltage divider in pin 3 or pin 6? @Jens

Answer (score 0):

The circuit needs only around 5 mA supply current, so a linear regulator like 78L05 or NCP730ASN330T1G will be fine here except you need a very low standby current. There is nothing wrong with your AP63205 step down.

The supply voltage can be read by ADC1 at pin 3 using a 6:1 resistive divider R3/R4.

I added R1 and C2 to filter out motor ripple voltage at the input of the regulator. This may be superfluous. The same could be said about C4.

Your FET Q1 (PMV100EPAR) is a P-FET and cannot work as intended in your circuit. You need a logic level N-MOSFET in this context and the load must be low side switched.

If you need a high side switch with P-FET, you need the N-FET in front of it as inverter and level shifter.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flwHg0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thank you Jens! just want to clarify 2 things, The motor is a 12V, 400mA rated current load(info i missed adding in my post). does the above circuit work for input voltage as 12V as well?

Comment: Yes, it works from 9 to 30 V. And what was the second thing to clarify?

Comment: The motor is a 12V, 400mA rated current load. Not a clarification but a note/information I missed adding. Thank you for your time and review.

Comment: Jens - You have mentioned the supply needs 5mA current but my load at peak will pull 400mA, Isn't that out of spec? would the above circuit have sufficient current for the DC load of 30 ohms?

Comment: @Adithi The mentioned supply current should be understood as everything except the motor current. During motor spinup I expect up to 4 A. If the supply voltage is 24 V, the maximum PWM duty cycle must be limited to 50 % to stay within the motor specification of 12 V.

Comment: I made a mistake in my initial circuit, we will be using a 12V motor and a 12V tactile switch regardless of whether the input is a 12V or a 24V. Is there a way around it where the motor and the switch can be fed with 12V regardless of the input? i dont want to add extra cost to the board.

Comment: @Adithi please explain why the voltage is important for the switch. As I wrote before: If you limit the PWM to 50% at a supply of 24 V the motor "sees" 12 V effective voltage. However the stress on the brushes is a bit higher compared to flat 12 VDC.

Comment: The motor will have 3 speeds: Low  (33% of duty cycle), Medium 66% duty cycle and High 100% duty cycle. I am worried if 100% duty cycle will burn the switch and the motor if the input is 24V. The same 3 speeds is applicable when the input is 12V as well.

Comment: @Adithi Yes, but what hinders you to set the duty cyles to 15.5, 33 and 50 % if the ADC detects a 24 V supply?